# Visualforce Pagination with custom Controller - Pagination not working

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to build a visual force page with custom controller to display data from two custom objects,

1. Purchase Order
2. Product Lot.

data from Product lot needs to be displayed using a table with pagination.

my pagination works when there is only one section in the page (Product lots section) but when both the sections are present (Details and Product Lots), pagination in the Product lots section doesnt work.

Here is my VF page:

```
<apex:page Controller="Purchase_Order_Controller" tabStyle="Purchase_Order__c"> 
  <apex:form > 
      <apex:sectionHeader title="Purchase Order Builder" subtitle="{!PO.name}"/> 

      <apex:pageBlock title="Purchase Order Builder" id="PgBlck1"> 
        <apex:pageMessages /> 
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Details" collapsible="false" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!PO.Name}"/> 
            <apex:inputField value="{!PO.Status__c}"/> 
            <apex:inputField value="{!PO.Budget__c}"/> 
            <apex:inputField value="{!PO.Store__c}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>              

        <apex:pageBlockButtons > 
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/> 
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>           
        </apex:pageBlockButtons> 

          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Product Lots" collapsible="false" id="PgBlkSection">          

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >  
              <apex:outputPanel id="Product_Panel">

                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!ProductLot}" var="plot">
                  <apex:column headervalue="Units">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!plot.Order_Line.Units__c}"/>
                  </apex:column>                      
                  <apex:column value="{!plot.Prod_lot.Name}"/>
                  <apex:column value="{!plot.Prod_lot.Product__c}"/>
                  <apex:column value="{!plot.Prod_lot.Product_Category__c}"/>
                  <apex:column value="{!plot.Prod_lot.Unit_Price__c}"/>
                  <apex:column value="{!plot.Prod_lot.Lot_Size__c}"/>
                </apex:pageblockTable>
                  <apex:commandButton value="First Page" action="{!FirstPage}" rerender="PgBlkSection" disabled="{!prev}"/>
                  <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!previous}" rerender="PgBlkSection" disabled="{!prev}"/>
                  Showing Page {!pageNumber} of {!totalPages} 
                  <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!next}" rerender="PgBlkSection" disabled="{!nxt}" status="Status"/>
                  <apex:commandButton value="Last Page" action="{!LastPage}" rerender="PgBlkSection" disabled="{!nxt}"/>            
                  <apex:actionStatus > id="Status" Starttext="Please wait..." </apex:actionStatus>

              </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>            
          </apex:pageBlockSection>                                                            
      </apex:pageBlock> 
  </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

**Here is my custom controller:**

```
public with sharing class Purchase_Order_Controller {

    public list<wrapper_Product_Order> Product_order {get; set;} 

    private integer totalRecs = 0;
    private integer OffsetSize = 0;
    private integer LimitSize= 2;
    public Purchase_Order__c PO {get;set;} 

    public Purchase_Order_Controller() {  
        Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        PO = (id == null) ? new Purchase_Order__c() :
            [SELECT Name, Status__c, Budget__c, Store__c FROM Purchase_Order__c WHERE Id = :id];

        totalRecs = [select count() from Product_Lot__c];
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        try {        
            upsert(PO);
        } catch(System.DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
        //  After Save, navigate to the default view page:
        return (new ApexPages.StandardController(PO)).view();
    }

    public PageReference cancel() {
    return null;
    }

    public class wrapper_Product_Order{

        public Product_Lot__c Prod_Lot {get; set;}
        public Order_Line_Item__c order_line {get; set;}

        public wrapper_Product_Order (Product_Lot__c pl){
            Prod_lot = New Product_Lot__c();
            Prod_lot = pl; 

            Order_line = New Order_line_item__c();            
            Order_line.units__c = 0; 
        }
    }       

    public List<wrapper_product_Order> getProductLot(){
        if (Product_order == null){
            Product_order = new list<wrapper_product_Order> ();
            for (Product_Lot__c pl: Database.Query('SELECT Name, Product__c, Product_Category__c, Unit_Price__c, Lot_Size__c FROM Product_Lot__c LIMIT :LimitSize OFFSET :OffsetSize')){
                Product_order.add(new wrapper_product_Order(pl));   
            }           
        }           
    return Product_order;
    }

    public PageReference FirstPage()
    {
        OffsetSize = 0;
        Product_order=null;
        return null;               
    }

    public PageReference previous()
    {
        OffsetSize = OffsetSize - LimitSize;      
        Product_order=null;        
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference next()
    {
        OffsetSize = OffsetSize + LimitSize;
        Product_order=null;
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference LastPage()
    {
        OffsetSize = totalrecs - math.mod(totalRecs,LimitSize);        
        Product_order=null;        
        return null;
    }

    public boolean getprev()
    {
        if(OffsetSize > 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

   public boolean getnxt()
    {
        if((OffsetSize + LimitSize) < totalRecs)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Integer getPageNumber() {
      return OffsetSize/LimitSize + 1;
   }

   public Integer getTotalPages() {
      if (math.mod(totalRecs, LimitSize) > 0) {
         return totalRecs/LimitSize + 1;
      } else {
         return (totalRecs/LimitSize);
      }
   }         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code and controller is that it needs to take into account that the 1st page holds Purchase Order info plus the start of your Product Lots details. It's the latter that causes the pagination.

Your controller needs to take this into account by calculating the pagination for the 1st page differently than it does the following pages. The subsequent pages shouldn't contain any of the Purchase Order info, but instead only the remainder of the Product Lots details. Doing this normally requires the controller to know how many lines can appear on Page 1 and how many lines can appear on the other pages.

An excellent example of how to do this is shown in [Creating Professional PDF Documents with CSS and Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_Professional_PDF_Documents_with_CSS_and_Visualforce) where the controller sets the number of break lines for the first page and for subsequent pages, then a method is called to set the breaks for the 1st page of quote lines and the subsequent pages to follow from the query results that have been returned as in the code below.

```
//controls how many quote line items are displayed on page 1
private static Integer FIRST_BREAK = 10;
//controls how many quote line items are displayed on subsequent pages
private static Integer SUBSEQ_BREAKS = 20;

public List<SFDC_520_QuoteLine__c[]> pageBrokenQuoteLines {get; private set; }

//splits the quote lines into an approximate number of rows that can be 
//displayed per page
private void prepareQuoteLinesForPrinting()
{
    pageBrokenQuoteLines = new List<SFDC_520_QuoteLine__c[]>();

    SFDC_520_QuoteLine__c[] pageOfQuotes = new SFDC_520_QuoteLine__c[]{};
    Integer counter = 0;

    boolean firstBreakFound = false;
       boolean setSubSeqBreak = false;        
    Integer breakPoint = FIRST_BREAK;

    for(SFDC_520_QuoteLine__c q&nbsp;: quoteLineItems)
    {
      if(counter <= breakPoint)
      {
         pageOfQuotes.add(q);
         counter++; 
      }
      if(counter == breakPoint)
      {
         if (!firstBreakFound) 
         {
            firstBreakFound = true;
               setSubSeqBreak  = true;
         }
         counter = 0;
         pageBrokenQuoteLines.add(pageOfQuotes);
         pageOfQuotes.clear();
      }
      if(setSubSeqBreak) 
         {
            breakPoint = SUBSEQ_BREAKS;
            setSubSeqBreak = false;
         }
    }
    //if we have finished looping and have some quotes left let's assign them
    if(!pageOfQuotes.isEmpty())
          pageBrokenQuoteLines.add(pageOfQuotes);
}
```